# Doesn't MS SQL server 2008 support optimization dynamically by subquery result?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, subquery

```
select * from big_table 
        where big_table_column1 > (select max(another_table_column1) from another_table) 
        and   big_table_column1 < 100000000
```

If max(another_table_column1) returns 200000000, so there should be no row to be retrieved.

Then when executing it on SQL server 2008 R2 enterprise, it takes long time, seems to retrieve data from big_table.

But when executing it on Oracle, it finished right now.

Seems SQL server doesn't do optimization dynamically by the result from the subquery, is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: How do the exeuction plans look like?

Comment: If `big_table_column1` isn't indexed and the plan shows a full scan you would probably need to break this up into two queries for the contradiction detection to kick in. The query `select * from big_table where big_table_column1 > 200000000 and big_table_column1 < 100000000` wouldn't access `big_table` at all. If it is indexed and you get a range seek then this should finish very quickly if the range is `> 200000000 AND < 100000000`

Comment: YASSOQ: Yet Another Select Star Optimization Question. And, I'm not talking about star join optimization.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Your deleted answer looks like it would do the trick. I rewrote it to use the (unindexed) tables in my answer and it adds a filter to the plan that reduces the rows to zero before the nested loops. [code here](http://pastebin.com/Rwi57kf4)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, but I discovered a small problem with the initial answer. I published my [updated] answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not detect this contradiction dynamically after evaluating the sub query. If `big_table_column1` is indexed and the plan shows a range seek then it won't make much difference but if it isn't you could optimise things by breaking the queries up and using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

The combined query does a full scan of big table.

[image]

Splitting into two allows it to not touch big table at all (the constant scan shows the contradiction was detected when the statement was recompiled)

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE big_table
  (
     big_table_column1 INT
  )

INSERT INTO big_table
SELECT TOP 1000000 v1.number
FROM   master..spt_values v1,
       master..spt_values v2

CREATE TABLE another_table
  (
     another_table_column1 INT
  )

INSERT INTO another_table
VALUES      (200000000)

/*Query 1*/
SELECT *
FROM   big_table
WHERE  big_table_column1 > (SELECT MAX(another_table_column1)
                            FROM   another_table)
       AND big_table_column1 < 100000000
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

/*Query 2*/
DECLARE @another_table_column1 INT

SELECT @another_table_column1 = MAX(another_table_column1)
FROM   another_table

SELECT *
FROM   big_table
WHERE  big_table_column1 > @another_table_column1
       AND big_table_column1 < 100000000
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

DROP TABLE big_table, another_table
```

Comment: After more investigation, Yes, If we have an index on it, then the performance is acceptable. But if we have no index on it, SQL server 2008 has bad performance, and Oracle has good performance instead. Maybe that's one gap between two of them. :)